# extract field using regex if only matching text exist in data

Tags: regex

I want to extract all occurance of a specific field from large log file. I have created a regex which is working fine.

The only thing i want to impove is that it should extract that field when specific text(CMS-initial-mark) present in that line.

Right now my regex extracts required field inspite of "CMS-initial-mark" present in extracted line.

PS: I am not using this specific for some lanugage. I will use this in SPLUNK which is data analysis tool.

Working Regex:

```
^[^,\n]*,\s+(?P<cms_initial_mark>[^ ]+)
```

Sample log file:

> *2017-06-20T12:17:49.238+0200: 103.708: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 968087K(1346344K)] 1066049K(2113128K), **0.0128291**
>   secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]
>
> 0.954: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 15929K(21888K)] 17147K(31680K), **0.0017910** secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]*

Output: 0.0128291 
        0.0017910

Comment: Can you not just add (.+) to your existing regex and capture all groups if group(1) is valid?

Comment: Why not `CMS-initial-mark[^,\n]*,\s+(?P<cms_initial_mark>[^ ]+)`?

Comment: @horcrux : Thank you! It worked for me :)